# Leave One Out Cross Validation : Best value of k for best accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, k-nearest-neighbour

I'm trying to find out the best value of k in the KNN method using LOOCV, which will result in better accuracy. But I'm unable to understand how to find out k using LOOCV.Let's say I take 1-NN, so I'd pick one, and then what?

[image]

Can someone help-out in finding the best value of k using LOOCV for the above pic?

Comment: Looking at this data, I don't know that k-nn is the best approach.  Think about self-teaching like a chain - it is only as strong as the weakest link.  In this case you are trying to understand a validation process, but what if the thing you are validating is fundamentally broken?  K-nn isn't necessarily fundamentally broken here, but it is quite weak.  I think that a perceptron and 2 SVM's would be much better at handling this.

Comment: Do you have the dataset for this picture? I really need it.

Answer (score 2):

For each chosen K, you'll calculate the performance metric of interest (let's say accuracy) using leave one out CV scheme. Then, choose the best `K`. This way, you optimise your hyperparameter, `K`.

Since, you don't have a separate test set, the final performance obtained with the best `K` might be a bit optimistic, compared to the real world data, but this is unrelated to your original concern, which is choosing the best `K`.